# Extract service in docker-compose to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file like so:

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

I'd like to take out that postgres service and have a seperate Dockerfile for it.
Any ideas however how that would look?

And in fact, is there any advantage of using Dockerfile's if I don't need to actually customise the base image in any way?

I was just thinking having some Dockerfiles handy, for whenever I want to get a service running say for local development.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need to customize the image it is better to use the base image, less things to maintain for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Compose fragment you have now is fine and you will gain nothing by writing it into a Dockerfile.

There are some options that can only be specified at the time you're running a container.  In this example, you can't specify `ports:` in a Dockerfile.  Typically for a database container you'll also want to specify some persistent storage, and again you can't specify this in a Dockerfile.

You could in principle move the environment variable setting into an image, but now you're hard-coding credentials in plain text into a built artifact, and they're very easy to retrieve back using `docker history`.

If the image you were running weren't already a complete packaged component then I'd generally recommend putting as much into a Dockerfile as you can.  Prefer Dockerfile `COPY` to Compose `volumes:`, build in a `CMD` rather than overriding a `command:`, put fixed `ENV` variables into the image.  Other services' host names and credentials like you show here still need to be specified at deployment time.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    <<: *fromTheQuestion
  app:
    build: .
    # No volumes: or command:
    environment:
      PGHOST: postgres
      PGUSER: ...
      PGPASSWORD: ...
      # But not NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # Run-time-only setting
```